# How to use an IP address to connect multiple clients to the L2TP/IPSec Linux server?

Tags: 16.04, vpn, ipsec

At home, I use a modem to connect to the Internet.
All mobile phones on the Internet are viewed with an ip address.(NAT)
I have a VPS Server.
I installed L2TP/IPsec service on it.
It works well. But only for the last person to be connected.
If someone else is connected to the server with a mobile phone with his own username, he only has the Internet and the Internet is interrupted by others.

I have noticed that the problem is from ip address. If one of the mobile phones is connected to Mobile data, the other VPNs will not be disconnected.

-Linux server version 16.04
-Configured done: [Configure Link](https://kayama.dp.ua/blog/ubuntu-16-04-how-to-setup-l2tp-over-ipsec-vpn-serv.html)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please include more information on your setup, such as IP's used, how it is configured (your *actual* configuration, not the tutorial you used),